# Setting ONLY WIDTH of a figure size, without height (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

I want to have a figure which is limited to the given size in width but its height is not set and is free to change.

The goal here is to define a figure which has a certain width but can change its height depending on the number of the variables that will be shown in the legend. Meaning, if we have more variables to show in legend, then the figure height will automatically adjust itself by getting longer (I am implementing a specific-sized border from all 4 sides, therefore, fixing figure height would crush the legend into the bottom of my subplots).

Of course I tried and just removing one component from `figsize` will not work (`Figure1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8))` gives an error).

Comment: The only way to do this is to first create a figure of defined size, then calculate the space needed, and finally resize the figure depending on the outcome of the calculation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Again, you are the first person to help me with my plotting problems, I really appreciate it.

That sounds like quite a pain. Which commands could I use to have the code calculate the required space for me?

Comment: You could start by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516501/make-identical-matplotlib-plots-with-y-axes-of-different-sizes/45521504#45521504).

Comment: Seems not possible. \
Quote: ```
[]
matplotlib does not "choose" a suitable aspect ratio per se. Instead, axes automatically fill to the size of the figure. Thus by setting the figure size with a (width, height) tuple you are also setting it's aspect ratio 
[]
matplotlib actually just uses a constant default figure size for all figures. This value is stored in the rcParams
<>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617263/matplotlib-set-width-or-height-of-figure-without-changing-aspect-ratio
``` \
Not familiar. Quote may be correct or not.